# Python: how to pass a function as a variable command in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

This is my first time creating a GUI using Tkinter to simulate a DSP setup. I'm stuck.

[image]

This GUI requires multiple scales. Therefore I wrote a generic scale  function.

```
# Overlap percent scale  
def overlap_percent():
    print("Testing")
    # op=var.get()
    # olive_features['overlap_perc']=op

    # generic scale function
def create_scale(self,parent,xval,yval,start,end,resolution,orient,default,lng,clr,cmdtrig):
    OHA_scale = tk.Scale(parent,resolution=resolution, from_=start, to=end, orient=orient,length=lng,fg=clr,command=cmdtrig)
    OHA_scale.grid(row=xval, column=yval, sticky=tk.E + tk.W + tk.N + tk.S, padx=20, pady=4)
    OHA_scale.set(default)


    # Overlap %
    yval=yval+2
    xval=1
    self.create_label(Oliveframe,xval,yval,"Overlap %")
    xval=3
    self.create_scale(Oliveframe,xval,yval,25,75,25,"vertical",75,90,'Black',"overlap_percent")
    xval=1
    yval=yval+1
    self.create_arrow(Oliveframe,xval,yval)
```

Based on the code above, i figured it would print 'Testing' on the cmd line, when i adjust the Overlap scale. Nothing happened. To test the code, i replaced the command in generic scale to

```
def create_scale(self,parent,xval,yval,start,end,resolution,orient,default,lng,clr,cmdtrig):
    OHA_scale = tk.Scale(parent,resolution=resolution, from_=start, to=end, orient=orient,length=lng,fg=clr,command=overlap_percent)
```

This resulted in an error.

*OHA_scale = tk.Scale(parent,resolution=resolution, from_=start, to=end, orient=orient,length=lng,fg=clr,command=overlap_percent)
NameError: name 'overlap_percent' is not defined*

I can't quite figure out what I'm doing wrong. How exactly can i use the generic scale function to control multiple scales?

Comment: where you modified the command function generic scale exactly

Comment: i modified my OP to highlight how i modified the command function.

Comment: "Based on the code above, i figured it would print 'Testing' on the cmd line, when i adjust the Overlap scale. Nothing happened." Well, yes; how exactly are you expecting `create_scale` to get called? Look at where the call is placed in your code. Did you perhaps want it to be in the `__init__` method? Or perhaps in some outside code, operating on a locally named instance rather than `self`?

Comment: For that matter, is `overlap_percent`  inside your class body? That's probably not what you wanted. But there isn't enough context here to diagnose the issue properly. Try to remove parts that are not related to the error, until you have the *smallest* code that is *complete*, *demonstrates* the problem and *can be run* by another person without modification.

Comment: If `overlap_percent()` is within the class, then `self.overlap_percent` should be used instead.

Comment: @acw1668. yes. i tried self.overlap_percent . That resulted in " TypeError: overlap_percent() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given " . So i didn't make any progress there either.

Comment: So you define `overlap_percent()` wrong, should be `def overlap_percent(self, value)` instead.

Comment: @acw1668 Yay. that works. thanks. But how can i make the command function self.xxxxxx, so that i can use the generic function for multiple scales?

Comment: You can pass an extra argument, for example `name`, to `create_scale(...)`: 
`def create_scale(..., cmdtrig, name):` and pass the name to the generic function: `tk.Scale(..., command=lambda v: cmdtrig(name, v)`.  Then define the generic function like `def some_function(self, scale_name, value):`.  You can then create scales like `create_scale(..., self.some_function, 'scale1')`, `create_scale(..., self.some_function, 'scale2')` and etc.

Comment: @acw1668 That really helped a lot. Xie Xie.

Answer (score 2):

on this line

```
OHA_scale = tk.Scale(parent,resolution=resolution, from_=start, to=end, 
orient=orient,length=lng,fg=clr,command=cmdtrig)
```

*command* take *function* parameters but you send a *string* value

```
self.create_scale(Oliveframe,xval,yval,25,75,25,"vertical",75,90,'Black',overlap_percent)
```

If you do it will be alright

Comment: I did try that before I posted my question. It ends up with an error 

NameError: name 'overlap_percent' is not defined 

similar to what I showed in the OP when i modified the scale function. I thought it might be due to the sequential order . so i played around with the order, still no luck :(

Comment: yes. i tried self.overlap_percent . That resulted in " TypeError: overlap_percent() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given " . i didn't quite understand how 2 arguments were given.